# Android webview not loading css and javascript when trying to access webpage using custom headers

Tags: javascript, android, css, webview, okhttp

I am using authorization headers to access the web page, but when using WebViewClient with authorization headers the webview not rendering the css and also the js not loading.

```
    public class TableViewTest extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    SharedPreferences pref;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_table_view_test);

        String url = "http://myurl";
        pref = getSharedPreferences("app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1Id);

        webView.setWebViewClient(wvc);
        //webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        //webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE);
            webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
        }
        //webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);

        webView.loadUrl("http://myurl");

    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        webView.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }


    WebViewClient wvc = new WebViewClient() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
            try {
                final String acToken = pref.getString("token", "DEFAULT");

                OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + acToken)
                        .build();

                Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();

                return new WebResourceResponse(response.header("text/html", response.body().contentType().type()), // You can set something other as default content-type
                        response.header("content-encoding", "utf-8"),  // Again, you can set another encoding as default
                        response.body().byteStream());


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                //return null to tell WebView we failed to fetch it WebView should try again.
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Please help me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Im facing the same problem. Have you find a solution?

Comment: @Picci My web service API developer solved the issue by creating style class for each one of the table element. Because the CSS referral via child classes are not loading in the web view. And after that, we changed to [link](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView). This is an awesome library. But we can not use the headers across all links in the web view. Its restricted to the initial request. Thanks for your effort to mention this. #HappyToHelp #HappyCoding

Comment: @Picci Actually my web view was loading a table format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used [AdvancedWebView](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView) library to overcome the issues. The default webview in android can not handle the css issues sometimes.

And also **both Android webview and AdvancedWebView Can not handle the headers except in initial request in the webview.** It can not pass the headers across all the links in particular webview request. Please refer this to rectify your doubts [Github Question](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView/issues/103).

My  [**SO Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41630491/delight-im-advanced-webview-send-custom-headers-with-every-get-post-request) for the headers issue.

If anybody finds the solution for the above header passing issue, feel free to add your solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

(btw is deprecated now)

```
WebViewClient wvc = new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (WebView view, String url){
                    try {
                        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
                        com.squareup.okhttp.Request request = new com.squareup.okhttp.Request.Builder()
                                .url(url.trim())
                                .addHeader("PIPPO", "PIPPO")
                                .build();
                        com.squareup.okhttp.Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();

                        Log.d("TAG",response.header("content-type", "text/html"));
                        Log.d("TAG",response.header("content-encoding",  "UTF-8"));

                        return new WebResourceResponse(
                                null,
                                null,
                                response.body().byteStream()
                        );
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        //return null to tell WebView we failed to fetch it WebView should try again.
                        return null;
                    }
            }
```

My only fear is that on smartphones with "problematic" default browser, the result may be broken.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I solved the issue by using this library  [AdvancedWebView](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView)

Comment: shouldInterceptRequest is a deprecated method.

Comment: @MuhammadMaqsood the original answer was 3 years ago, I'm adding a note.