# Antd CSS not loading in Android native Webview

Tags: android, webview, antd

I am using antd@5 and nextjs server if that is relevant.

When I load my page in normal browser, then it works fine but when it is loaded in Android webview then the Antd5 CSS does not load.

I have already referred the question , [Android webview not loading css and javascript when trying to access webpage using custom headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41530051/android-webview-not-loading-css-and-javascript-when-trying-to-access-webpage-usi)

Using AdvancedWebView is not an option.

Comment: To use antd with mobile devices I think you should take a look into [ant design mobile](https://mobile.ant.design/guide/faq/)